# Java agent is mandatory for jmockit test case on java 6?

Tags: java, jmockit

i am using java 6. If i run the jmockit test with java agent `-javaagent:C:\jmockit-1.20.jar` , it works fine. But if i remove it i get below error

```
java.lang.Exception: Method testData_1 should have no parameters
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java:69)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(ParentRunner.java:131)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateTestMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:178)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:344)
```

As i read on internet  that on JDK 1.6+  attaching java agent is no such requirement, since JMockit can transparently load the Java agent on demand by using the Attach API.
But then why its throwing error without java agent ?

Answer (score 2):

As you use `JUnit` to execute your tests, either

- Make sure that `jmockit.jar` appears before `JUnit` in the classpath
- or annotate test classes with `@RunWith(JMockit.class)`
- or set the Java Agent option

Any of these options allows `JMockit` to initialize itself properly before `JUnit` starts running.

Comment: tried with  `@RunWith(JMockit.class)` and remove java agent. Does not work . Same errror

Comment: Ah, well, maybe this has nothing to do with `JMockit` then? The error says your test method has parameters defined which is invalid. So remove the `@Test` annotation from `testupdatePaymentData_1` or remove the parameters of that method.

Comment: well if i remove @Test, it is not recognized as test case. Also i can't remove  the parameters of that method as i need them.

Comment: Of course it is not recognized as test if you deannotate it. For what do you need the parameters? When JUnit has to execute the test, how should it know what to give as values to the parameters? It cannot know, thus parameters are not allowed.

Comment: Parameters in the test method (annotated with `@Mocked`, etc.) are provided by JMockit, unless it failed to get initialized. If that stack trace still appears when using `@RunWith(JMockit.class)`, then the problem is something else.

Comment: Ah, well, then maybe @Mocked is missing?

Comment: @Rogério Do you mean  jomick test case should ideally run with just `@RunWith(JMockit.class) ` and no need to give java agent  for jdk 1.6 and above ?

Comment: @emilly which of the three methods I listed in my answer is up to you, but all are absolutely equal in their effect (just looked at the sources) as long as the Attach API is available in the VM running the tests. If not, the first and second method would not work, but error out and you would have to use the command line option way. If it does not work with the command line option way, your problem is not that JMockit is not loaded or initialized. As I asked before, do you actually have the `@Mocked` annotation on the method parameters (not on the method)?